# MYSQLI Object oriented, what's wrong with my script?

Tags: php, oop, object, mysqli

I'm trying to do an execution of a query and see if it goes well, but right now it doesn't enter the IF or ELSE.
I had it on mysqli procedural and all worked flawlessy now I'm trying to change it to object oriented and it won't enter inside if/else.

```
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $email = $_POST["email"]; 
    $password = md5($_POST["password"]); 

    $query = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Email=? AND Password=?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $email,$password);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    if ($result->num_rows == 1)
    {
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                alert("INSIDE");
            </script>
        <?php
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        if(isset($_POST['remember']))
        {
            $_SESSION["remember"] = "1"; 
        }
        $_SESSION["username"] = $row['Username'];
        $_SESSION['check'] = "1";
        $_SESSION['ID'] = $id;
        $_SESSION['permission'] = $row['Admin'];
        header("Location: dashboard.php");
        exit;
    } 
    else
    {
        ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                alert("Credentials Are Wrong!");
            </script>
        <?php
        exit;
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Thank you all.

Comment: It'd be a lot easier to tell you what's wrong with it if you'd tell us what the problem is. Please include the error this returns, and what's supposed to happen instead.

Comment: It doesn't execute the query, it gives error when executing query

Comment: Have you looked into using `fetch()` instead of `query()`?

Comment: `md5()` is not strong enough encryption.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51259779/2943403

Comment: Can't mark as dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/a/52720089/2943403 because no votes on my answer.

Comment: **DO NOT** use `md5()` as encryption. Use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` instead.

Comment: @LucaVerdecchia If your script is halted before the if/else, then there will be an error.  We need to know what that error is.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using

```
$stmt->bind_result($col1, $col2 ...);
```

and

```
$result = $stmt->fetch();
```

in order to access the data from the query, rather than

```
$conn->query($stmt);
```

(an example is provided at https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php). Note that for this to work you will need to specify the column names you want to fetch from the database, rather than using * in your SQL query, and for each column data is fetched from in the query, you should have a variable for in the fetch() parameters, so for example, something as follows should work (note these may not match the names of your database columns):

```
$email = $_POST["email"]; 
$password = md5($_POST["password"]); 

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT ID, Name FROM Users WHERE Email=? AND Password=?");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $email, $password);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $name);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();
echo $id . ': ' . $name;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer**

You are very close.  Use `$result = $stmt->get_result();` instead of `$result = $stmt->query;` to check to see if the query returned a result or not.

```
$email = $_POST["email"]; 
$password = md5($_POST["password"]);     

$query = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Email = ? AND Password = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $email, $password);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

if($result->num_rows !== 0){

  if(isset($_POST['remember'])){
    $_SESSION["remember"] = "1"; 
  }

  $_SESSION['check'] = "1";
  $_SESSION['ID'] = $row['ID'];
  header("Location: dashboard.php");
  exit();

}else{

  echo
  '<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Credentials Are Wrong!");
  </script>';

  exit();

  }

$stmt->close();
```

As several have already stated in their comments do not use MD5 for password hashes.  PHP has it's own built in functions for handling passwords.  Please research [Password_has()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [Password_verify()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).  Spend the time to research and implement these now instead of later.  It will save you time.

Comment: Thanks for the responce, and I will surely see php functions for password hash! But I've done as you told and now it seems that it doesn't go inside IF or ELSE. Check my original post for the new version of the code

Comment: Run `echo $result->num_rows;` before the if statement and tell me what it says.

Comment: There is some error as browser says 500 error, so there is an error on the code but dreamviewer doesn't tell me anything about errors. If i remove $result = $stmt->get_result(); the browser doesn't display any 500 error

Comment: I've updated the answer, If i remove $result = $stmt->get_result(); the browser doesn't display any 500 error

Comment: Are you sure that $password & $email have populated values?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure they are populated as I've for this moment manually populated them for be 101% sure about it

Comment: Sorry, I do not see where your error is at.  Your code should work.

Comment: I would make sure your mysqli error reporting is turned on and that you set your PHP error reporting to all.